# Run multiple site on a single instance in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, multiple-sites

I have three different website.
can we run on a single instance in  umbracocms.
how can  i map three different website in single umbracocms and host on serv

Answer (score 3):

You can, but that doesn't always mean that you should. If you want three different sites, you can have three root nodes, and set the hostname for each of the sites to the domain that you want to use. Once you've done that, just point the three domain names at your IIS website, and you should be good to go.

You'll need to make sure that you set all of the back office permissions properly if you don't want the users to be able to each of the sites. If the sites are all for the same client, and have common design, then hosting in one instance is probably OK. If they're all different and for different clients, it'll be much easier to manage them as separate Umbraco sites, IMHO.

Comment: As Tim says, don't do this unless there is a solid reason to do so.  Umbraco is not a web server.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup the content tree in your Umbraco backoffice.

Create a home node for each website and setup the correct hostnames.

After that view this wiki page that explains what needs to be done at your server.

https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multiple-websites-on-one-umbraco-installation